# I need to abort an NUnit test execution as soon as the user types "stop". How do I achieve this?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a console application written in C#. The solution is written using .NET Core 3.1 . From the console I am running NUnit tests. The console application runs "dotnet test" command to run a test. Now, if the user types "stop" in the console then I need to immediately stop the execution of the tests.
So far I have tried,

```
 string input = Console.ReadLine();
 if(input == "stop")
 {
   Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
 }
```

This kills the process but only after finishing the entire test execution. That is not what I want. I want it to stop/abort instantly.
How do I achieve this in NUnit ?

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to kill the `dotnet test` process. How is the console application running `dotnet test`? Are you starting it programmatically, using `Process.Start`?

Comment: @parakeet. Yes, I am able to kill the dotnet process. But, are you aware of any test listeners that I can use ? I heard that NUnit has listeners that I can use. 
FYI, I am using NUnit 3.0